# Strange critical error with my desktop

Tags: cpu, crash

I recently reinstalled because my harddisk was on an old hardrive from a laptop with a write speed of 60MB/s. While I was at it I installed a new CPU heatsink. When I removed the old stock one the CPU was attached to the heatsink, taking it out bent one of the pins, but I bent it back. I then et up RAID 0 and installed the new heatsink.

Everything seems to work fine, after windows does a million updates, then installs a service pack then a few more updates (still not upto date) I launched some games on steam, and my monitors shut down, so does my mouse and keyboard but the fan in the tower are still whirring away. I have to restart and in the event viewer (I'm not so good at looking through it) I have just one  critical error:  me pressing the restart button.

This seems to happen on random occasions, it may not happen for a day or an hour then I assume all the I/O ports shut off.

any of you had this problem, it could be the bent pin, I did do a bit of overclocking aswel, but only for a few days at a 900MHz faster so I do not think it would damage it much, plus my CPU seems to throttle itself when it gets to 60 degrees Celcius. It has never passed that, even on stock cooler, it seems to not just happen now during games, it happened today after I locked the computer.

I have run 2 stress tests because someone thought my powersupply was not good enough (600W by the way) the 2 stress problems where AIDA64 and OCCT

parts are:

motherboard: Gigabite GA-990FXA-D3
processor: AMD FX 8120 3100 Mhz CPU
Cooler: Cooler Master Hyper 212
EvoGFX Card: Gigabite based AMD Raedon 7950 1000mhz 3gig

Comment: Too many things have changed at the same time to make easy diagnosis possible. However the first thing which I noticed it that the CPU now gets hotter and that you changed the heat sink. Combine that with the emergency stop feature which many motherboards and CPUs trigger on overheating and I would start with checking the heat sink. Make sure that you new heat sink is properly attached, that there is enough fresh (bit not to much) thermal paste. Run something like CPU-Z to monitor the CPU's heat and then start a new stress test. Either a game, prime95 or something similar.

Comment: @Hennes I did as you asked, at idle cpu temproture was 13 degrees, during the stress test with prime95 it went to 35 degrees.

Comment: 35°C is surprisingly low. It rules out a CPU overheating problem. As is the 18°C at idle temperature. Though I would almost call it unbelievable low. What is your room temperature? 10°C / 50F ?

Comment: @Hennes im not sure, its 11°C outside, its a little warmer inside

Comment: @Hennes i went into the bios, it said that the cpu was 30°C so maybe the sensor is broken, but i tried doing a complete reinstall, windows inst detecting one of my hard drives and the other 2 it said it cant install on there even tho they are a primary disk, please check the logs, but the installation disk i dont beleave has logs, or i just cant see how i can view them

Comment: Are two two drives on which it can not install set to some RAID mode? (The [GA-990FXA-D3](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3900) seems to support RAID 0/1/5/10)? Does it help if you load [additional drivers](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/Pages/raid_windows.aspx#2) during the installation?

Comment: @Hennes they where, i changed the mode back to native IDE and it didnt like it for some reason so i put it back on raid and redefined it and now windows installs, i cant test if the crashing happens again til bout 8pm, its 3:30am currently, thanks for the help so far, realy appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely the bent pin is the issue here. Either it still is in contact with the socket, or it is not and your machine would probably not even be able to reach the BIOS stage.

I consider the new heat sink to be the problem. Did you properly apply a heat conductor when installing it?

Comment: yes, im running 10 degrees cooler at idle (18 degrees celcius)